# Why essential supremum would fail if essup is replaced by sup?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know that $\Vert f\Vert=esssup_{x} \vert f(x) \vert=0$ if and only if $f(x)=0$ a.e., but why this property would fail if ess sup is replaced by sup? The sup means that $\Vert f\Vert =\sup_{x} \vert f(x)\vert$

Comment: "Functions" in $L^p$ spaces are not really functions, but equivalence classes of functions that are equal almost everywhere. The supremum isn't well-defined, since it depends on the particular choice of representative for the equivalence class. This is not the case for the essential supremum.

Comment: Yes, it would.  On the interval $[0, 1]$, let $f(1) = 1$, and $f(x) = 0$ for $0 \leq x < 1$.

$$\sup_{[0, 1]} |f(x)| = 1,$$
but
$${\tt ess }\sup_{[0, 1]} |f(x)| = 0,$$
and the essential supremum is the one consistent with the equalities
$$
|| f ||_{p} = 0, \quad p \geq 1.
$$